# Issue with Google test framework and OpenCV

Tags: testing, segmentation-fault, googletest

I am new to Google Test Framework and trying to explore it. I tried some simple example and it all worked.

But when i was testing my OpneCV program (No functionality used from opencv as of now, only added header files) with gtest then it gave me segfault. for an example

```
#include<iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

    //for gtest API
    #include "gtest/gtest.h"   ///for google test framework

int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}

TEST(Test, EqualityCheck) {

ASSERT_EQ(1,1)<<"Test Passed";
}
```

if compiled it without openCV linking then everything worked fine

```
g++ -o out cv_gtest.cpp -I/usr/local/include -I./inc  /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a
```

but if compiled with opencv linking we get seg fault at runtime

```
g++ -o out cv_gtest.cpp -I/usr/local/include -I./inc  /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ImageTest
[ RUN      ] Test.EqualityCheck
[       OK ] Test.EqualityCheck (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from Test (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
After debugging with valgrind (partial output)

    ==8284== Invalid read of size 4
==8284==    at 0x34C049D4B6: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==8284==    by 0x4394DD: void std::_Destroy<std::string>(std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x4388A3: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x436D92: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x433D98: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x42E879: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x34B943613C: __cxa_finalize (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x7613545: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x767D1B0: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x34B9435DA1: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x34B941ECE3: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==  Address 0x7d99e98 is 8 bytes before a block of size 11 free'd
==8284==    at 0x4A05B26: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:515)
==8284==    by 0x425A0E: testing::internal::String::~String() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x43A326: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String>(testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x439CCA: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<testing::internal::String*>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x4392F1: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String*>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x438470: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*, std::allocator<testing::internal::String>&) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x43AED3: std::vector<testing::internal::String, std::allocator<testing::internal::String> >::~vector() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x34B9435DA1: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x34B941ECE3: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284== 
==8284== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==8284==    at 0x4A05FD6: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==8284==    by 0x34C049D4C8: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==8284==    by 0x4394DD: void std::_Destroy<std::string>(std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x4388A3: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x436D92: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x433D98: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x42E879: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x34B943613C: __cxa_finalize (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x7613545: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x767D1B0: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x34B9435DA1: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x34B941ECE3: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==  Address 0x7d99e88 is 24 bytes before a block of size 11 free'd
==8284==    at 0x4A05B26: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:515)
==8284==    by 0x425A0E: testing::internal::String::~String() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x43A326: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String>(testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x439CCA: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<testing::internal::String*>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x4392F1: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String*>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x438470: void std::_Destroy<testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String>(testing::internal::String*, testing::internal::String*, std::allocator<testing::internal::String>&) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x43AED3: std::vector<testing::internal::String, std::allocator<testing::internal::String> >::~vector() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x34B9435DA1: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x34B941ECE3: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284== 
==8284== 
==8284== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8284==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2
==8284==    at 0x34C049D4B6: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==8284==    by 0x4394DD: void std::_Destroy<std::string>(std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x4388A3: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x436D92: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x433D98: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x42E879: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /home/sairam/Desktop/sagar/CV_GTEST/colormap)
==8284==    by 0x34B943613C: __cxa_finalize (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x7613545: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x767D1B0: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5)
==8284==    by 0x34B9435DA1: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==    by 0x34B941ECE3: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==8284==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==8284==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==8284==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==8284==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==8284==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==8284== 
==8284== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8284==     in use at exit: 2,283,560 bytes in 183 blocks
==8284==   total heap usage: 742 allocs, 560 frees, 3,695,829 bytes allocated
==8284== 
==8284== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8284==    definitely lost: 750,084 bytes in 4 blocks
==8284==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8284==      possibly lost: 1,503,662 bytes in 73 blocks
==8284==    still reachable: 29,814 bytes in 106 blocks
==8284==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8284== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8284== 
==8284== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

Comment: Can you run it inside a debugger and give us the backtrace after it crashes?  I am not familiar with pkg-config so I am not sure what it does.

Comment: Also, please include the output of `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`. What's probably happening is that the pkg-config command is giving you a compiler option which is incompatible with the compiler options that were used to create the libgtest.a static library.